# Python : call a function and wait for its thread(s) to finish

Tags: python, gdb, python-multithreading

I am using Python to script a gdb session. My goal is to run a function whenever a breakpoint is hit, using `gdb.events.stop.connect`.

Here is my code in essence, which I call from gdb by running `source main.py` :

```
RESULT = None


def breakpoint_handler(event):
    global RESULT
    RESULT = do_something(event)  # boolean
    sleep(1)


def main():
    global RESULT
    gdb.events.stop.connect(breakpoint_handler)
    command = "some gdb command"
    gdb.execute(command)
    sleep(1)
    if RESULT:
        # do something
        pass
    else:
        # something else
        pass

main()
```

This code works, but only thanks to the `sleep` calls, that tries to make sure the `gdb.execute(command)`call actually finish executing the gdb command before continuing. There is only little documentation but my guess is that this function is threaded, which explains the effectiveness of the `wait`as a fix.

Is there a way to make this cleaner by waiting for the thread created by `gdb.execute` to finish processing, without having access to the body of this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an event inside your callback and wait for it in your main thread. Here is an example, with the callback being called after 5 seconds by timer:

```
import threading

def some_callback():
    event.set()

event = threading.Event()
threading.Timer(5, some_callback).start()
event.wait()
```

Comment: @Paupaulaz "event" with "evt"? THAT what bothers you? Really?

Comment: ahaha @borislipschitz I'm sorry I wanted to correct the import statement being outside of the code but needed to modify something more so that the edit could be submitted, and there was not much else to change ..

Comment: @Paupaulaz, lol, i didn't even notice the import went outside the code section. Anyway, use events, don't use arbitrary sleeps :-)